# d3.js force layout graph : how to build the nodes object from scratch?

Tags: javascript, json, hyperlink, d3.js, nodes

I am trying to adapt the following d3.js force layout to my own needs :
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

When I use the following json file, everything displays fine (2 nodes and 1 link) :

```
    {
     "name": "parent",
     "children": [
          {"name": "child1", "size": 100}
     ]
    }
```

Then I want to build the nodes object from scratch; so, in the above mentioned reference example, I replace the `flatten()` function with the following one :

```
    function flatten1() {
      var nodes = [];
      var node = {name: 'child1', size: 100, id: 1};
      nodes.push(node);
      node = {name: 'parent', children: [{name: 'child1', size: 100, id: 1}], id: 2};
      nodes.push(node);
      return nodes;
    }
```

and the `update()` function now begins with :

```
var nodes = flatten1(),
links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
```

Of course, I don't use the json file anymore.
When I check the content of nodes and links, it looks similar to the previously working code (with the json file), but there is a display problem : the 2 nodes are ok, but the link goes from the parent node to the upper left corner of the svg block...

What did I miss ?
Any help would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the node that you pass into the second node as a child needs to be a reference to the first one, not the new Object that you are creating. Try this;

```
function flatten1() {
  var nodes = [];
  var node1 = {name: 'child1', size: 100, id: 1};
  nodes.push(node1);
  var node2 = {name: 'parent', children: [node1], id: 2};
  nodes.push(node2);
  return nodes;
}
```

If that works then it gives you some idea on how to shape the rest of your flatten algorithm.